# how do i update the card title dynamically which i received as param?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-native

param which is received in this function

```
function Details(props) {

  const cardTitle = props.route.params.cardTitle; // this is a header Title

  CardTitle(cardTitle)  // passing the value to CardTitle function

    return (
    <View>        
      <CardPollScreen/>     
    </View>
  );
}
```

i want to access the cardtitle value and update in this title. So i passed those values to CardTitle(cardtitle) function. after receiving the value in the function. when i try to access the value in the  `<Card.Title title ={cardtitle} />`[this is the errror iam getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST0UT.png)

```
function CardTitle(cardtitle){
  return (
    <View style={{marginLeft:-50}}>
    <Card.Title
            title= {cardtitle}
            subtitle='3:10 PM Tuesday, November 12'
            left={LeftContent}
            titleStyle={{
              fontSize: 12,
              marginTop: 1,
              marginLeft:-10
            }}
            subtitleStyle={{
              fontSize: 12,
              marginTop: 0,
              padding: 0,
              lineHeight: 13,
              marginLeft:-10
            }}
            right={ (props) =>
            <IconButton icon='more-horizontal' style={{marginRight:0}} color={Colors.black} size={25}/> 
            }/>
            </View>        
  );
}
```

this is stack for the screen

```
  <FeedStack.Screen 
  name='Details' 
  component={Details} 
  options={{ headerTitle: props => <CardTitle {...props}/> }} />
  {/* <FeedStack.Screen name='Opinions' component={Opinions} /> */}
  <FeedStack.Screen
    name='Topics'
    component={Topics}
    options={{
      title: null,
    }}
  />
```

i tried many methods nothing helped much.

Comment: Replace `<Card.Title title= {cardtitle}` with `<Card.Title title="Card Title"`  See if error gone

Comment: no! actually i want to update the title value which i received as an argument in the function.

Comment: It is useless to call `CardTitle` like that, you should call it inside the returned JSX, not outside.